# How can I implement and load an Android ISO into a C# WinForm application?

Tags: c#, winforms, android-emulator, touch

My task is to create a C# WinForm application that looks something like this:

[image]

On the one hand there should be buttons with touch functions which do things on the Android system as well as a button which starts and stops the Android.

In the other half of the WinForm application the Android should be embedded and show the touch functions of the buttons.

I've tried to embed an Android ISO into a C# application using a PictureBox and display it this way. However, this didn't work. Even trying to start and embed the android with xamarin didn't work.

Does anyone have an idea how I can implement this functionally?

Comment: Are you just ask us to write an android emulator for you?

Comment: @vasily.sib No, I'm just asking if anyone knows how to start and use an Android ISO embedded in a WinForm.

Comment: ISO - is just a file format. There is no such thing like _"ISO embedded in a WinForms"_. It doesn't work the way you think. To _"start and use an Android ISO"_ you need an android emulator first. There is plenty of them, just google a little.

Comment: Do do this, you need to write an android emulator, so the first comment of @vasily.sib still stands

Comment: @vasily.sib I was looking for some Android emulators like BlueStacks or Nox. But I couldn't get it to embed them.

Comment: Ok, now it's looks like XY-problem. Why do you ever think that you need to embed them? Why don't you just use them?

Comment: @vasily.sib Because I want to have the "Android Emulator" and the Windows Forms application in one program and not program and emulator separately.  Do you understand?

Comment: I understand that and I'm telling you that trying to create your own Android emulator alone is a madness. It's also looks pretty much like XY-problem. **WHY** do you ever think that you need to embed them? **WHY** don't you just use them separated?